# Why am I getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'` error?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, importerror

When I run my Python script, I get the following message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

I'm running Python 3.6 on Linux Ubuntu.
The script named Fax_simulator contains:

```
import Image
# other code…
```

It's place in:

```
/home/CVS/facsim/venv
```

I've searched for the module and I've found it:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py
```

Here are some lines of the code:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
```

Do I have to install it. And if Yes how? With PIP? I've got the PIP version 9.0.1 from Python 3.6. Is that alright?

Comment: ``Image`` is a *submodule* of ``PIL``. Its fully qualified name is ``PIL.Image``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import them from the `PIL` package:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

# use Image
```

Or alternatively:

```
import PIL

# use PIL.Image
```